# Encounter errors when compiling program using QT5.6 on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I **want to compile a program called uartassistant using QT5.6 on windows 10,I encountered this error**:

> g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o debug\uartassistant.exe
>   debug/main.o debug/dialog.o debug/hled.o debug/moc_dialog.o
>   debug/moc_hled.o  -lmingw32 -LF:\qt\5.6\mingw49_32\lib
>   F:\qt\5.6\mingw49_32\lib\libqtmaind.a -LC:\utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib
>   -LC:\utils\my_sql\my_sql\lib -lshell32 -LE:\uartassistannew\uartassistant\build -lqextserialportd1 -LE:\uartassistannew\uartassistant\analogwidgets -lanalogwidgets F:\qt\5.6\mingw49_32\lib\libQt5Widgetsd.a
>   F:\qt\5.6\mingw49_32\lib\libQt5Quickd.a
>   F:\qt\5.6\mingw49_32\lib\libQt5Guid.a
>   F:\qt\5.6\mingw49_32\lib\libQt5Qmld.a
>   F:\qt\5.6\mingw49_32\lib\libQt5Networkd.a
>   F:\qt\5.6\mingw49_32\lib\libQt5Cored.a 
>   E:\uartassistannew\uartassistant\analogwidgets/libanalogwidgets.a(manometer.o):manometer.cpp:(.text+0x44a):
>   undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK7QString3argEdiciRK5QChar'
>   E:\uartassistannew\uartassistant\analogwidgets/libanalogwidgets.a(manometer.o):manometer.cpp:(.text+0x11f8):
>   undefined reference to`_imp___ZNK7QString3argEdiciRK5QChar'
>   E:\uartassistannew\uartassistant\analogwidgets/libanalogwidgets.a(manometer.o):manometer.cpp:(.text+0x1570):
>   undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK11QMetaObject2trEPKcS1_'
>   E:\uartassistannew\uartassistant\analogwidgets/libanalogwidgets.a(manometer.o):manometer.cpp:(.text+0x178a):
>   undefined reference to`_imp___ZNK11QMetaObject2trEPKcS1_'
>   F:/qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   E:\uartassistannew\uartassistant\analogwidgets/libanalogwidgets.a(manometer.o):
>   bad reloc address 0x24 in section
>   `.text$*ZplRK7QStringS1*[__ZplRK7QStringS1_]' collect2.exe: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status Makefile.Debug:71: recipe for target
>   'debug\uartassistant.exe' failed mingw32-make[1]: ***
>   [debug\uartassistant.exe] Error 1 mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory
>   'E:/uartassistannew/build-uartassistant-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
>   makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed mingw32-make: ***
>   [debug] Error 2 Error while building/deploying project uartassistant
>   (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 MinGW 32bit) When executing step "Make"
>   12:14:13: Elapsed time: 00:18.

I compiled the same program on windows 7 using QT,no error happened.

Anyone can help me deal with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it the same Qt binary in win7 and in win 10? Do you compile Qt yourself?

Comment: not same ,in win7. I used version 4+ I think.I forgot.I just download qt program,not compile it from source.